# How to use the real parameters when creating a stub method in RhinoMocks?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, stubbing

I want to create a stub of the following interface:

```
interface IUnitOfWork
{
   void DoInTransaction(Action method);
}
```

In the stub object, all I want `DoInTransaction` to do is run `method()`.

Something like:

```
// pseudo-code
unitOfWorkStub.Stub(x => x.DoInTransaction(method)).Do(method())
```

Is it possible to create this kind of a stub with RhinoMocks? How can this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use this:

```
unitOfWorkStub.Stub(x => x.DoInTransaction(Arg<Action>.Is.Anything))
              .WhenCalled(x => ((Action)x.Arguments[0])());
```

Comment: @IlyaKogan is this question specific to passing `Action` or does it apply any time you want to be able to call a stub method with non-fixed parameters?

Comment: @Mr.Boy This question is from 2011 :)

Comment: @IlyaKogan so what? It was my google result and seemed reelvant

Comment: @Mr.Boy I mean that I can't answer your question because I can hardly remember what RhinoMocks is, not to speak of specific questions I had about it :)